# Azure VM can't receive incoming SIP request

Tags: azure, sip, windows-firewall

I am trying to run my SIP client on Azure VM for the first time. I have added endpoints to the VM to allow SIP traffic (UDP 5060). I have disabled the windows firewall on the Win2012 R2 VM. Even the ACL is set to 0.0.0.0/0 in the VM endpoints settings.

When I send a SIP INVITE from Internet, I can see the INVITE on wireshark, but it never reaches the SIP client. I even tried eyeBeam client instead of my SIP application, same result. Wireshark can see the INVITE SIP packet, but it never reaches the application.

Since wireshark can see the SIP packet, my Azure settings may be OK. But who is stopping the packets from reaching the SIP client?

I tried tracert from the VM, it returns a blank, to any public IP. For example:

```
tracert www.microsoft.com

Tracing route to lb1.www.ms.akadns.net [134.170.188.84]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 20     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 21     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 22     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 24     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 25     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 26     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 27     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 28     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 29     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

Comment: Is there a TTL on that request?

Comment: I looked at the SIP & SDP fields. There is no TTL. But you bring up an interesting point. Whenever I make a call, I get 6 INVITE request within couple seconds. The INVITE comes from a SIP trunk provider, when I dial a DID number provided by them. I am thinking of dialing directly from a SIP client now.

Comment: I tried tracert from the VM, it returns a blank, to any public IP. Fro example:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I solved the problem. I am posting the image of the Azure endpoint settings. See the option I have circled in red, that should be left unchecked. I was selecting that option, and that totally messed me up days.

[image: Azure Endpoint Settings]